# Editing .resx files on a Mac

Tags: macos, resx

Is there any app that I can use to edit .resx files on a Mac running OSX?

I just need to be able to edit string resources.

**Edit**. I know .resx files are XML files. However, I am looking for an app that can edit .resx files using a clean user interface, very much like Visual Studio does, hiding the complexity of the XML. I don't want users to be able to accidentally modify the XML structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, not directly. However, .resx files are XML, so you if you're comfortable with their syntax, open them in your favorite plain-text editor (XCode, BBEdit, whatever) and hack away.

### Edit based on the update to the question

Nothing, as far as my Google-fu can find, currently exists to fill this need. However, .resx files are *relatively* straightforward XML, so if you have a Mac and XCode, you can probably whip up something with an `NSTableView` that operates similarly to Visual Studio's in-box .resx editor for strings.

Now, it's considerably less trivial to support other resource formats (particularly binary data), but strings at least shouldn't be terribly complicated.

I wish I could give you a "proper" answer, but unfortunately, I simply cannot locate anything appropriate. I see many .resx editors out on the web, but all are for Windows. To get you started building something (I know this wasn't your intent, but it's likely your only answer), check these APIs:

- [Mac XML APIs, courtesy of Apple's Developer site.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/CFXML.html)
- [`NSTableView` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView)
- [`NSTableViewDataSource` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDataSource)

If building something is truly not viable, your other option is to either virtualize Windows (using VMWare Fusion or Parallels Desktop), or to use Boot Camp and create a Windows partition. Then you can install any of the zillion and one .resx editors for Windows -- or even a Visual Studio Express instance, which will also contain .resx editing in-box.

Comment: Thanks, but an XML would give the users the opportunity to accidentally alter the XML structure. I need an app that gives users a "clean" user interface to just edit the resource strings. I have added an edit clarifying that. Sorry I didn't say it before.

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive response, John. Shame that there's no native support for .resx files on OSX.

Comment: Hi, i'm looking for one,  i mean we're 6 years in, have you find any ? please any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There is now a macOS app for editing regex files in the App Store.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/resx-editor/id1484612171?mt=12

I've just started using it, so I can't offer much of a review, but it does seem to work fine so far, and at that price, I figured it was worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

The best App is [ResX Editor](https://apps.apple.com/pa/app/resx-editor/id1484612171?mt=12), it is for Mac user.

It do the job like a charm! this is worth it for 2$!

You can get it for free on source forge

Answer (score -1):

If you are still looking for an option for your mac, I used an extension (free) for VisualStudio Code called ResXpress: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrateekMahendrakar.resxpress